# Detecting a connection to a distinct circuit with no current return

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I hope the title is informative, and that I'm not posting a repeat - part of my problem here I believe is that I don't know the correct terminology to find the answer on the internet as a whole.

The specific situation here is in the sport of fencing, and the diagram below depicts the circuit created within an epee - with the top button-switch being pressed, and completing a circuit, when the fencer scores a hit with their sword. However, when the hit is on the opponents sword, it's not desirable to score a hit (as it's not a valid one).

I'm wondering how one could detect the condition shown below in Figure B, where a very simple circuit with a closed switch has a conductive connection to a part of another circuit, with no return path for current.

[image]

I know that [another device](http://www.hitmate.co.uk/documents/EpeeHitmateUserGuide.pdf) can do it, their guide suggests that the green wire (in my diagram) is kept close to each fencers body to provide an 'earth reference'. I'm confused about what this means - would you try to detect some current leakage, or other change in the voltage/current/resistance characteristics, when the circuit is connected to a new ground voltage?

Comment: the green wire connects the body to the epee. there is another circuit that measures the capacitance of the epee tip. if large capacitance is measured, then the LED is inhibited. that is why the device (that you linked to) does not register a hit when the opponent's tunic is soaked in sweat ... it works like the touchscreen used in smartphones

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I'm struggling to understand a little how the epee tip gains a large capacitance when it's connected to the green wire - and how to measure it. 

Don't I only have access to one side of the capacitor, so to speak, formed by the green wire in proximity to the opponents body? I'm not sure how you measure the capacitance of a capacitor without measuring the voltage across them!

Comment: some info ... http://www.softnoze.com/downloads/Sensor%20Basics%203.pdf